# How Huffman tree construction have element in left and right

Tags: huffman-code

I am trying to create a Huffman code from some frequencies. I know how to do that but i have only one confusion that in which side (left or right ?) we will put which element.

I mean what i have in mind for Huffman tree is-
(1) First we sort in decreasing order all the frequencies.
(2) take the smallest two and merge them. ** But i don't understand which of the two frequencies will go in right and which will go in left** and i know that in right side we have '0' and right side we have '1'. but which frequency is to be kept in right or left taht i don't know. On what basis we do that ?

Comment: Ummm, exactly how does this question relate to CSS, as in cascading style sheets?

Comment: @ppeterka66 i got a suggestion below to tag it there. thats why i done it. sorry for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the child node in left or right thatis immaterial of the overall solution.we will see the length only not these values 0 & 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't exactly understand your question I'll give you a quick example of huffman encoding:

```
A: 0.5
B: 0.1
C: 0.2
D: 0.15
E: 0.05
```

Now in descending order of frequency:

```
A: 0.5
C: 0.2
D: 0.15
B: 0.1
E: 0.05
```

Now we combine the bottom two:

```
A: 0.5
C: 0.2
D: 0.15
B+E: 0.15
```

We continue to do this until we have a completely binary tree. In this example:
`A = 0, C = 10, D = 110, B = 1110, E = 11110`
It doesn't matter if we choose to continue the tree with a 0 or 1 as long as your decompressor knows how to read it.

Comment: My question is when you do B+E then will B come in right side (where we go on '0' or in left where we go on '1') ?? Understood now ?please let me know

Comment: So huffman encoding works in a way that if it sees a 0 it will stop reading bits but if it sees a 1 it will continue reading. This allows you to have differing lengths for each character. Example decompressor loop: `1 (continue), 1 (continue), 1 (continue), 0 (stop)` It now looks at the binary codes and finds the matching character.

Comment: so in your example(B+E) where you would have kept 'B' in left or right ??? and why ?? that's my question exactly is.

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as both your encoder and decoder do it the same way.